# Polygon not showing on ThingsBoard Trip Animation Widget

Tags: polygon, thingsboard

I am currently trying to mess around with ThingsBoard, and one of the things I am trying to achieve is to show a polygon on the trip animation widget. I have my coordinate values added to it as I would expect to work, but it doesn't seem to.

I have tested the same collection of coordinates on the general 'Latest Values' map widget and it works fine there, but I would really like to visualize the movement of a device between polygons.

Has anyone gotten the polygon working that may be able to advise?

My coordinates field is a timeseries value and in the format *[* **[** [l1,l2],[l1,l2] **]**,**[** [l1,l2],[l1,l2] **]** ,...**[** [l1,l2],[l1,l2] **]** *]*

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?
Any advice that can be given is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have talked with ThingsBoard devs, there is an actual bug in the widget. It is not appearing because it is broken, closing this question